# Install Jquery files in yii

Tags: jquery, yii, yii-components

I searched all over internet and I still don't have a clue how to install it, I used the calls to jquery files but doesn't work, I have found in many places that you have to use `registerscriptcore('jquery');` I put it in my layout but still doesn't work..

how to do this if i want to load jquery libraries and custom libraries?

this is how i am trying.

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="language" content="en" />
        <!-- blueprint CSS framework -->

        <?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/print.css" media="print" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/jqueryui/js/jquery.js"></script>
<!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/jqueryui/js/jqueryui.min.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/jQueryte/jqueryte.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/jQueryte/jqueryte.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/drag/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/drag/script.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/form.css" />
        <title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>
</head>
```

Comment: what is the url you are seeing in html source?

Comment: try to hint this line:
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/css/jqueryui/js/jquery.js"></script>
as jquery is already included in the core script registration call

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it as following,

```
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScriptFile('my.js');
```

for more information. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript